# $X_1, X_2$, ... independent variables with support in [0,1] , mean $\mu\in(0,1)$, $Y_n=X_1X_2...X_n,\;\;\;n\geq1$. Study convergence of $Y_n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

$X_1, X_2$, ... independent variables with support in the interval [0,1] and equal mean $\mu\in(0,1)$, but not necessarily identically distributed. Study the convergence in quadratic mead and convergence in probability that $Y_n=X_1X_2...X_n,\;\;\;n\geq1$

Convergence in probability:

If for every $\epsilon>0$, $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=0$, then  $X_n$ converges in probability to X.

Convergence in quadratic mean:

If $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} E((X_n-X)^2)=0$, then  $X_n$ converges in quadratic mean to X.

Answer (score 1):

$(Y_n)$ is non-negative and decreasing so $Y =\lim Y_n$ exists almost surely, hence in probability. By Bounded Convergence Theorem it also converges in quadratic mean.

Comment: (Yn) is non-negative and decreasing implies Y=limYn exists almost surely?    What would be the value of Y?

Comment: It is the infinite product $X_1X_2\cdots$. All the hypothesis about independence and mean or irrelevent.

Comment: Why (Yn) non-negative and decreasing implies Y=limYn exists almost surely??

Comment: If you have a positive an decreasing succession and Yn converges in probability to Y, then Yn converges almost sure to Y. Thatis true or maybe I was wrong?

Comment: That is true. The sequence converges a.s. and the limit in probability has to be the same as a.s. limit.